# Word VBA : Searching particular strings on pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to search many articles names on a big ms-Word document, So, im asking how can i do something like this ???

```
'To find exactly this string
    Selection.Find.Text = "Article : KR"
'To find all the other strings ("Article : [NOT KR]")
    Selection.Find.Text = "Article : [!KR]"
'To compare Strings, i need to make a test, like this
    IF Selection.Find.Text = "Article : ^?^?" <> "Article : KR" Then Call SearchAndMarkx("artKR")
'To build a case structure maybe with the tests 
Case Selection.Find.Found "Article : KR" do ...
Case Selection.Find.Found "Article : IP" do ...
```

I want to know how to write these instructions.
I need to know how to make this ! i searched a lot, and the result i want still not found!
Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to match that pattern fairly easily. The following will match Article : KR(Followed by a space or paragraph break) and then match Article : [!KR](Followed by a space or paragraph break)

```
Sub FindTags()

Dim myRange
Set myRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Content

Dim myFind
Set myFind = myRange.Find

Dim base
base = "Article : "
Dim srch
srch = base & "*[^13 ]"

While (myFind.Execute(FindText:=srch, MatchWildcards:=True))
    Dim difference, rangeLength, srchLength, text
    rangeLength = Len(myRange.text)
    srchLength = Len(base & "KR")
    difference = rangeLength - srchLength
    If (difference > 1) Then
        'Process your Article : [!KR] here
        text = Mid(myRange.text, Len(base) + 1, Len(myRange.text) - Len(base) - 1)
    Else
        text = Mid(myRange.text, Len(base) + 1, 2)
        If (text <> "KR") Then
            'Process your Article : [!KR] here
        Else
            'Process your Article : [KR] here
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```